# Parametric solution of linear system when the parameter diverges

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, asymptotics, linear-transformations

Let $A_1,A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (both non singular) and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$such that for all $\lambda \geq 0$ the matrix

$$
A_\lambda = A_1 + \lambda A_2
$$

is non singular as well.
I want to study the asymptotic behavior of the solution of the linear system

$$
A_\lambda x = b
$$

when $\lambda \to +\infty$, and my guess is that the solution $x \rightarrow 0$, this is my argument.

Let $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ be any norm, if the norm is of a matrix the the norm I'm considering is the one induced from the vector norm.
If I consider
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} \lVert A_\lambda \rVert = \lVert \frac{1}{\lambda} A_1 + A_2 \rVert \Rightarrow \lVert A_2 \rVert - \frac{1}{\lambda} \lVert A_1 \rVert \leq \lVert \frac{1}{\lambda} A_1 + A_2 \rVert \leq \lVert A_2 \rVert + \frac{1}{\lambda} \lVert A_1 \rVert
$$
Since when $\lambda \to +\infty$ we have $\frac{1}{\lambda} \lVert A_1 \rVert \to 0$ then $\lVert A_\lambda \rVert \to \lambda \lVert A_2 \rVert$. Similarly we can state $\frac{1}{\lambda} \lVert b \rVert \to 0$. Therefore if $x_\lambda$ is the solution of the system $A_\lambda x = b$ then I can say that $x_\lambda \to 0$ because the system to be solved is

$$
A_2 x = 0
$$

but $A_2$ is not singular, therefore the solution is unique, and it must be the zero vector.

I guess a similar argument can be applied if I drop the non singularity assumption, in such a case my guess would be that the solution set is the kernel if the linear transformation defined by $A_2$.

Is all my argument correct?

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong ! You wrote:

$\lambda \lVert A_\lambda \rVert = \lVert \frac{1}{\lambda} A_1 + A_2 \rVert $.

But $\lambda \lVert A_\lambda \rVert = \lVert \lambda A_1 + \lambda^2 A_2 \rVert $.

Comment: how about now? I've edited my post.